Is it possible to obtain the return type of useFetch in nuxt3?
I want to specify the APIBody type as follows, but it results in an error: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'NonNullable<PickFrom<_ResT, KeysOf>>'. Is there currently no way to specify the return type of useFetch? If so, it feels very inconvenient...
type APIBody = {
 test: string
}
const {data, error} = await useFetch<APIBody>("api_url here")

console.log(data.value.test) // Property 'test' does not exist on type 'NonNullable<PickFrom<_ResT, KeysOf<DataT>>>'.



Afaik, JSON doesn't have a type in itself. But you could use zod to type the schema that you want to have with the received payload.

The data property returned by the useFetch function as stated in the Nuxt docs is a Vue Ref and therefore must be accessed via it's .value property inside of <script setup>.
Here is an example with proper typing:
<script setup lang="ts">
type APIBody = {
  test: string
}

const { data, error } = await useFetch<APIBody>("<api_url>")

console.log(data.value.test) // Typed as APIBody['test']
</script>


Sorry this is my mistake. I did actually data.value.test, but  I got the error.

I changed the text of my question.

The return type of useFetch is Ref<APIBody|null>, because the default value is null before the fetch is successfully finished.
You can use Optional Chaining:
console.log(data.value?.test) 

Or specifying a default value:
const { data, error } = await useFetch<APIBody>("<api_url>",{default: ()=>({test:''}))
console.log(data.value.test) 

